# How to plot multiple categorical data using scatter plot assigning different color?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two columns of categorical variables and I want to plot each of the columns against same x-axis.

for example for the following csv file, I want to plot type and assign color according to status. For example, type a is represented as 'x' and type 'b' is represented as 'o'. If type 'a' has status 'yes' then its green else red and same for type'b'.

```
start_time,type,status
2017-08-21 13:41:39.899,a,yes
2017-08-21 14:11:21.283,b,yes
2017-08-21 14:22:09.590,b,no
2017-08-21 14:27:56.175,b,yes
2017-08-21 15:51:07.950,a,yes
2017-08-21 17:37:37.959,a,no
2017-08-21 18:53:37.040,b,yes
2017-08-21 18:54:34.282,a,no
2017-08-21 20:36:36.180,b,yes
2017-08-21 20:42:23.579,a,no
```

I tried using matplotlib, `plt.scatter()` but couldn't get what I desired.Please help. Also, I have used start-time as index in pandas dataframe.
Edit :
X- axis is start_time

Comment: You provided an excerpt of a dataset with categorical values. What data for x-axis and y-axis?

Comment: You only have types `a` and `b` or how many types do you have?

Comment: only two types 'a' and 'b'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to plot scatter on `x=start_time` and `y='y'`, you can use `sns.scatterplot`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
sns.scatterplot(x='start_time', y='y',
                style='type',
                hue='status',
                data=df,
                ax=ax)
ax.set_xlim(df.start_time.min(), df.start_time.max())
plt.show()
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think You could perform what you desire by creating smaller dataframe which contains each categories you desire to isolate ( a& yes, a & no, b & yes and b & no) by performing this :

```
a_and_yes= df.loc[(df['type']=='a') & (df['status'])=="yes"] # for each categories
```

Then, you can select the different value that interest you in this dataframe, and scatter each with the desired style

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is split your data from the csv in "yes" and "no" dataframes and plot them separately with different colors:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

csv_data = pd.read_csv("data.csv") # csv file containing data provided in question description
df = pd.DataFrame(csv_data)

yes = df[df.status == 'yes']
no = df[df.status == 'no']

plt.scatter(yes.start_time, yes.type, marker='o', c='green')
plt.scatter(no.start_time, no.type, marker='o', c='red')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

The above code will lead to the following plot (sry for the axis labels being cut off in my screenshot):

[image]